# Java Swing - On a Mac, listening for Quit event

Tags: java, macos

In a Java application on a Mac, you can click the top bar and select Quit to exit the program. How can I add a listener to my JFrame to listen to this?

I did a search on this and found ApplicationListener, however Eclipse puts a "cross out" in this and seems to think its deprecated or something.

Specifically, I found to use com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener, but how do I do this? Do I need to download this com.apple.eawt package? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the newer version QuitHandler, available from Apple Java extension

Answer (score 2):

In Java 9, you should use the cross-platform Desktop API, as the Mac EAWT APIs have been deprecated:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    desktop.setQuitHandler(new QuitHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleQuitRequestWith(QuitEvent evt, QuitResponse res)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the quit request
            // res.cancelQuit();  // Cancel the quit request
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an ApplicationListener:

There is a sample application available from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

For Java 7, QuitHandler is the interface to be implemented.

```
import com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler;
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
```

somewhere, do the following:

```
Application macApp = Application.getApplication();
macApp.setQuitHandler(this);
```

and then ,

```
@Override
public void handleQuitRequestWith(AppEvent.QuitEvent qe,final QuitResponse qr) {
    System.out.println("quit clicked");
    qr.performQuit();

}
```

I got hints from CodeGuy and the following url
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7113349/jdk8/webrev.4/jdk/raw_files/new/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt/Application.java

Answer (score 0):

You can catch when cross out button clicked like this

```
frame.addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
```

And then you can overwrite it like this

```
 public class ExitListener extends WindowAdapter{
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            //some codes
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work with Quit, I'm afraid: the window is not really "closed" and the listener is thus not called.

Answer (score 0):

To not to break compatibility with Windows and other OSes here is approach with another approach:

http://javadots.blogspot.com/2010/09/making-your-swing-app-macosx-compliant.html

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simplericity.macify</groupId>
    <artifactId>macify</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```