# Why won't this shutdownhook work?

Tags: java, swing, events, shutdown-hook

This is my main method and it contains a shutdownhook:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shutdown hook");
        }
        });

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
}
```

The problem is the `JOptionPane` doesn't show up at all. Instead, the frame closes but the app itself still runs. 
PS. I can't use the `WindowClosing` event because it doesn't fire on the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> command on *Mac OS X*.

Comment: Maybe its because the awt event dispatcher was already shutdown when shutdown hooks are executed?

Comment: Definitely don't use Shutdown hook. Find another mechanism.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10076104/261156)?

Comment: From the the javadoc of addShutdownHook: `Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly.` So I guess displaying a dialog is a really bad idea. You should rethink why you need a shutdown hook.

Comment: Whatever they are good for, interacting with the GUI is way beyond that.

Comment: OK - so apparently showing a pop up message from shutdown hooks is a bad idea. I guess I'll try something else. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispatch thread is already shut down, or is likely to be shut down before your submission to the queue is executed.

You need to find another way of trapping the quit events, shutdown hook is there so you can tidy up when the VM is exiting, so you really don't want to by tying up more resources in the UI when it is called.